# Circle of the Moon druid CR discrepancy for Wild Shape on D&D Beyond

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, dnd-beyond

I want to play a druid that can go into Wild Shape, so I'm building him on D&D Beyond.

The [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#WildShape-167) feature says that at 4th level, I can Wild Shape into a CR 1/2 beast, and at 8th level I can Wild Shape into a CR 1 beast.

However, the article ["Druid 101: Wild Shape Guide" by James Haeck](https://www.dndbeyond.com/posts/635-druid-101-wild-shape-guide) says that at 2nd level, I can Wild Shape into a CR 1 beast, and by 6th level, I can Wild Shape into a beast with a CR of my druid level divided by 3 (rounded down), so a CR 2 beast at 6th level.

Which one is right?
Or does the [Circle of the Moon druid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#CircleoftheMoon)'s [Circle Forms](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#CircleForms-186) feature (PHB, p. 69) negate the Wild Shape feature?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### The article is correct, becuse of the modifications the Moon druid subclass does to the Wild Shape feature

Specifically, Moon Druids get the [Circle Forms](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#CircleoftheMoon) feature which explicitly overrides the CR restrictions of the normal Wild Shape (emphasis added):

> Starting at 2nd level, you can use your Wild Shape to transform into a beast with a challenge rating as high as 1 (*you ignore the Max. CR column of the Beast Shapes table*, but must abide by the other limitations there).
>       Starting at 6th level, you can transform into a beast with a challenge rating as high as your druid level divided by 3, rounded down.
>
> — *Player's Handbook*, p. 69

This is an example of Specific Beats General, a principle outlined on page 7 of the *Player's Handbook* ([which is also in the Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/introduction#SpecificBeatsGeneral)) and reiterated on page 5 of *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*.